# Core Data no longer firing binding on changes to relationship

Tags: xcode, macos, core-data, xcode7

I'm using MVVM for a number of complex views where I bind a Core Data model object to a view model which is in turn bound to my view.  For example, Model.children is bound to ViewModel.children and ViewModel.children is bound to View.presentedChildren.

Until recently this worked great.  When deleting a child from Model.children, all of the bindings fired down the line as expected and the view updated to reflect the current state of the model object. Since upgrading to Xcode 7 however, the bindings don't fire.  They work as expected when setting the binding initially however if the children relationship is modified, the binding never fires.

A KV observer added to the children relationship of the model object does fire.

I'm missing something obviously. Any tips would be much appreciated.

FYI Compiling against 10.11 but running in 10.10.

**[UPDATE]**

I've replaced the bind: calls on the relationships with addObserver: and implemented observeValueForKeyPath: as follows:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *)change context:(void *)context
{
    [self setValue: [object valueForKey: keyPath]
            forKey: keyPath];
}
```

This works but doesn't explain what has changed in the implementation of bind: for NSObject or NSManagedObject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've adopted Reactive Cocoa bindings for this area of my app as well and things work again.